# Set Product Custom Options From Observer Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, custom-options, programmatically

I am trying to add custom options to products on save. I want to add or update custom options (not additional options) on before_product save. I am able to access the observer and it is working on save as well but unable to update the custom options. Create option code is working if run from standalone script but not from observer only.
This is my observer code

```
class Company_Module_Model_Observer{
    public function updateOptions($observer){
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $categories= $product->getCategoryIds();
        $currentCategory = '';

        foreach ($categories as $cat_id){
            $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id);
            $currentCategory = $cat->getName();
        }

        $skuList =['LAPTOP_','DESKTOP_'];
        $upgrades = $optionValues =  [];
        if($currentCategory=='Laptops'){
            $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('like' => 'LAPTOP_%'));
            $upgrades = $_productCollection;
        }
        $meta = "6 this is product meta with custom plugin ".$product->getName();
        foreach ($upgrades as $products) {
            $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($products->getId());

            $optionValues = array(
                'title' => $_product->getName(),
                'price' => $_product->getPrice(),
                'price_type' => 'fixed',
                'sku' => $_product->getSku(),
                'sort_order' => 0,
            );
        }

        $options = array(
            'title' => 'Upgrades',
            'type' => 'drop_down',
            'is_required' => 0,
            'sort_order' => 0,
            'values' => $optionValues
        );
    
        $product->setMetaDescription($meta);
        $product->setProductOptions(array($options));
        $product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
        //if uncomment this then save loop continues and site hangs
        //$product->save();
    }
}
```

No error in logs or anything else. Please guide me how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
  $product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
                if ($customOptions = $product->getProductOptions()) {
                    foreach (array_keys($customOptions) as $key) {
                        $customOptions[$key]['custom_value'] = "value";
                    }
                    $product->setProductOptions($customOptions);
                }
```